# Is there an easy way to remove end of the string in rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm new into Python/pandas and I'm losing my hair with Regex. I would like to use str.replace() to modify strings into a dataframe.

I have a 'Names' column into dataframe df which looks like this:

```
Jeffrey[1] 
Mike[3]
Philip(1)
Jeffrey[2]
etc...
```

I would like to remove in each single row of the column the end of the string which follows either the '[' or the '('...

I thought to use something like this below but I have hard time to understand regex, any tip with regard to a nice regex summary for beginner is welcome.

```
df['Names']=df['Names'].str.replace(r'REGEX??', '')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Extract only the alphabetic letters with `Series.str.extract`:

```
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)')

     Names
0  Jeffrey
1     Mike
2   Philip
3  Jeffrey
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex would work, with `$` indicates the end of the string:

```
 df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.extract('(.*)[\[|\(]\d+[\]\)]$')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `split` to take everything before the first `[` or `(` characters.

```
df['Names'].str.split('\[|\(').str[0]

     Names
0  Jeffrey
1     Mike
2   Philip
3  Jeffrey
```